# Updating a view controller without replacing all content

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I am creating an application where the user can try on different pairs of glasses.

The mainView controller has two IUImageViews, (photo and the glasses). This view controller also has two buttons, (take photo and select photo). Once the user swipes or taps the navigation button a side navigation appears of which the user can select a pair of glasses to try on.

This works however only when the user has selected a pair of glasses THEN takes or selects a photo instead of the other way round because the photo gets completely overridden when a pair of glasses is selected.

This leads me to wonder how and if I can allow it so the view is not overridden so if the user takes a photo and then selects a pair of glasses, the photo would stay there and then the pair of glasses would appear too.

Now onto the current code:

The each pair of glasses has a button on the navigation, this is an example of one of the buttons...

```
  - (IBAction)glass_one_pressed:(id)sender{  
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imageChangeSegue" sender:nil];}
```

The segue looks like this...

```
//Segue for glasses one
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"imageChangeSegue"]) {
    NewViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    secondViewController.theImageForTheImageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glasses_one.png"];
}
```

Image of storyboard: http://postimg.org/image/rcjfai52d/

I hope I've explained everything well enough, if not I have uploaded the project for you to have a look at.

Download Zip: https://mega.co.nz/#!9hxmjSZT!L7UFGpKBC5CsQQtuPGh0SVfRN4TdxLLRvh6jJW-TmD0

Any help would be very much appreciated. Please note that I am new to iOS development and I work in web development so the difference between coding in Objective-C and PHP is massive aha.

Many thanks,
Zack.

Comment: I think you need a different paradigm to make this work. When you select a pair of glasses, instead of segueing to a new controller, it should take you back to the one with your picture on it, and the glasses need to be in an image view that's added over top the face, and it needs to be draggable, so you can move it where you want. The glasses image also needs to have a transparent background which they appear not to have currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you every time create a new NewViewController.

```
//Segue for glasses one
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"imageChangeSegue"]) {
    NewViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    secondViewController.theImageForTheImageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glasses_one.png"];
}
```

You should hide the navigation controller instead, or save the picture shown in the actual NewViewController and set it also in the new one.

---

In SidebarViewController.m add this method to prevent the segue to being executed.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"imageChangeSegue"] || [identifier isEqualToString:@"glasses_two"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Change the handler like this:

```
//When glasses one button is pressed...
- (IBAction)glass_one_pressed:(id)sender{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    SWRevealViewController *contr = (SWRevealViewController *)appDelegate.initialViewController;
    //close the sidebar
    [contr revealToggleAnimated:YES];
    //set the new image
    appDelegate.myNewViewController.glassView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glasses_one.png"];
}
```

In NewViewController add:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.myNewViewController = self;
}
```

In AppDelegate.h add:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *initialViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NewViewController *myNewViewController;
```

In AppDelegate.m add this line to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    //save the SWRevealViewController
    self.initialViewController = (SWRevealViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniele, thanks for your help. I was wondering if you would be able give me some example code or direct me to the right place to learn how to hide the navigation controller or to save the picture within the NewViewController to make this possible. I have had a little Google and tried different things but I haven't succeeded as of yet. Thanks again, Zack.